# Persisting a bi-directional One-To-Many Association fails with Eclipse Link 2.7.4

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, payara

I am trying to persist a simple bi-directional One to many relationship, but with eclipse link 2.7.4 it fails.  Below is the sample code..

### Department Entity (Parent)

```
@Entity(name = "Department")
@Table(name = "department")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Cacheable(false)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Department")
public class Department {

    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private long id;


    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
    @XmlElement(name = "employees", type = Employee.class)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @Version
    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    private long version;

    public long getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

### Employee Entity (child)

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * The id.
     */
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Department.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Department department;

    @Version
    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    private long version;

    public long getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }


    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

### Test class

```
public class Test {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "pun";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Department department = new Department();
        List<Employee> dists = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setDepartment(department);
        dists.add(emp1);

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setDepartment(department);
        dists.add(emp2);

        department.setEmployees(dists);
        em.persist(department);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
    }
}
```

### persistence.xml (Used Derby Embedded DB)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="pun" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!--  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> -->
        <class>demo.eclipselink.error.Department</class>
        <class>demo.eclipselink.error.Employee</class>
         <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:derby:/databases/simpleDb;create=true" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

          <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
          <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
          <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />

          <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
         </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Once i run the code using Eclipse Link 2.7.4 it gives me the following exception stack track.

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column name 'DEPT_ID' appears more than once times in the column list of an INSERT statement.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO employee (dept_id, id, VERSION, dept_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

I cannot reproduce this issue with v 2.7.3 and fails only in 2.7.4. We are using eclipse link along with Payara 5.191 and this issue exists there as well.

Please let us know if there is a work around.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a bi-directional one-to-many association. You have two independent associations instead. If you want a bidirectional association, you need `mappedBy` on `@OneToMany`. The `@JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")` on `employees` then becomes redundant

Comment: @crizzis Thanks for your response. The same code is working in Eclipse Link 2.7.3 but fails with 2.7.4. Do you think there is some thing wrong in the code? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The source object must use the `mappedBy` attribute to define the mapping.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_relationship_and_inverse_ManyToOne_annotations